# Rails nested resources with pretty URLs for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The data for my application is structured as:

- Organizations have users
- Organizations have messages
- Organizations have sites

I would normally use nested resources to do this RESTfully:

```
resources :organizations do
  resources :users
  resources :messages
  resources :sites
end
```

Which gives me URLs like:

```
/organizations/12/messages
/organizations/12/sites
```

These wordy URLs are excellent for when an admin needs to create a message for an organization because the URL contains the organization ID.

**However**, I would like to show normal users pretty URLs such as:

```
/messages
/sites
```

Is there a way to alias these pretty URLs to /organizations/{current_user.organization.id}/* ?

Comment: what do you mean by /organizations/{current_user.organization.id}/*  ?

Comment: You mean you want your admin user can see they are many organization and normal user can't see it ?

Comment: @Awea: Yes - I would like admins to be able to add messages and change sites for all organizations, so the longer URLs are useful in that case.

Comment: Why you didn't use different namespace to split logic for user in a part and for admin in an other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to pass organization id.
For example, if you have a user who belongs to organization and the user is signed in,
You can get organization id via current_user as following:

```
class MessageController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :get_organization
 # ...
private
  def get_organization
    @organization = current_user.organization
  end
end
```

And, in your routes you can add:

```
resources :messages
resources :organizations do
  resources :messages
end
```

There are other solutions but it depends on how you can get organization id.